# php Memcached Connection timeout

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

k, so im having some troubles with the following

```
$this->cacheServers = array(
     array('test.com', 11211)
);

$this->memcache = new \Memcached();
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, TRUE );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, TRUE );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_CACHE_LOOKUPS, TRUE );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 50 );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_POLL_TIMEOUT, 50 );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_RECV_TIMEOUT, 10000 );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_SEND_TIMEOUT, 10000 );

$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT, 1 );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT, 50 );

$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_NO_BLOCK, TRUE );
$this->memcache->setOption( \Memcached::OPT_TCP_NODELAY, true );
$this->_data['connected'] = $this->memcache->addServers($this->cacheServers);
```

so, im trying to get it to timeout, but it just hangs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implemented my own telnet test with `fsockopen` and a one second timeout.

Answering my own question yet again

Comment: Seems confusing that there is a memcache and a memcached extension for PHP.

Comment: Memcache is the older, worse one. Memcached is the newer, better one.